# Semantic correct html for image checkbox

Tags: css, html, image, checkbox

What is the semantically correct HTML (HTML 5) markup for images that can be selected or deselected and should behave as checkbox in a form. Semantically, the images are not just styling of the checkboxes, but rather the actual objects that are selected.

Comment: Do you want it semantically or do you want it actually working? You cannot have both.

Comment: wat action you need to perform based on that clicks

Comment: the images/checkboxes are part of a form and the destination should know the checked-ness of each of them... i.e. standard checkbox behaviour in a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would place both the image and the checkbox in a `label` element:

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" />
</label>
```

This way you associate the image with the checkbox, and activating the image will toggle the state of the checkbox.

You can also hide the checkbox and use `:selected + img` to style the image depending on the checkedness.

```css
label {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
label > input {
  opacity: 0;
}
label > img {
  opacity: .4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label > :checked + img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" />
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" />
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" />
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" />
</label>
```

Comment: Indeed, I would like to hide the checkbox, and manipulate the image to show the selection state. I do not mind doing this in JS, but JS-free would certainly be nicer...

Comment: Ah, you gave the answer before I finished my comment... Thanks!

Comment: @burnpanck If you want to hide the checkbox, be aware `display: none` isn't accessible (it can't be toggled with the keyboard). You can use `opacity: 0` to hide it, `position: fixed` to make it out-of-flow, and negative `left` and `top` to place it outside the viewport.